# Como verificar se um tipo é numérico em C++?

Tags: c++, template, assert

Vamos supor que eu tenho uma função:

```
template<class T>
T soma(const T& x, const T& y) {
    static_assert(/*O tipo é for numérico?*/, "Tipo de argumento inválido, O argumento precisa ser numérico");
    return x + y;
}
```

Dá pra saber se o tipo `T` é numérico?

Comment: acho que aqui tem tudo https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se está usando uma versão mais antiga do C+= tem que recorrer a alguns truques para obter o resultado esperado. [No SO tem uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37617906/221800) com um deles. Tem [outras fontes](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/07/simulate-static_if-with-c11c14.html) que indicam truques. Ou pode fazer assim:

```
static_assert(is_arithmetic_v<T>::value, "Must be arithmetic");
```

Se já estiver usando C++ 17 e precisar fazer mais que um `assert`. tem algo na linguagem que ajuda muito que é o [`if constrexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). Exemplo:

```
template<class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};
template<class T>
T soma(const T& x, const T& y) {
    if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>)
        return x + y;
    else
        // faz alguma coisa aqui
        static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "Must be arithmetic");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Template/IsNumber.cpp).

- [Legal para saber mais](https://www.meetingcpp.com/blog/items/How-if-constexpr-simplifies-your-code-in-Cpp17.html)
- [Paper de como chegou aí](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html)
- [Exemplos com comparação para o C++ 14](https://hackernoon.com/a-tour-of-c-17-if-constexpr-3ea62f62ff65)
- [Mais exemplos](https://tech.io/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/constexpr-if)

E finalmente se puder esperar pelo C++ 20 poderá fazer uso de [Concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) que é a solução definitiva. As opções acima são paliativos porque a linguagem não pode expressar em código restrições no uso da variável gabaritada de forma direta.

Comment: estou usando c++ 17

Answer (score 4):

A partir do `C++11` você pode usar a função [`std::is_arithmetic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) da biblioteca padrão [`type_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) para verificar se um tipo arbitrário se trata de um número inteiro ou real (ponto flutuante), veja só:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "A:           " <<  std::is_arithmetic<A>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "bool:        " <<  std::is_arithmetic<bool>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "int:         " <<  std::is_arithmetic<int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "int const:   " <<  std::is_arithmetic<int const>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "int &:       " <<  std::is_arithmetic<int&>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "int *:       " <<  std::is_arithmetic<int*>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "float:       " <<  std::is_arithmetic<float>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "float const: " <<  std::is_arithmetic<float const>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "float &:     " <<  std::is_arithmetic<float&>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "float *:     " <<  std::is_arithmetic<float*>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "char:        " <<  std::is_arithmetic<char>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "char const:  " <<  std::is_arithmetic<char const>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "char &:      " <<  std::is_arithmetic<char&>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "char *:      " <<  std::is_arithmetic<char*>::value << '\n';
}
```

Saída:

```
A:           false
bool:        true
int:         true
int const:   true
int &:       false
int *:       false
float:       true
float const: true
float &:     false
float *:     false
char:        true
char const:  true
char &:      false
char *:      false
```

No seu caso:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
T soma(const T& x, const T& y) {
    static_assert( std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Tipo de argumento inválido, O argumento precisa ser numérico");
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por me ensinar sobre o std::boolalpha